# When does malloc() in C return NULL?

Tags: c, null, malloc

Malloc returns a null when heap memory is insufficient OR when heap is super fragmented.

What I would like to know is that if there are OTHER circumstances when malloc() returns a NULL?

PS:[Under what circumstances can malloc return NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9101597/10701114) didn't seem to answer my question

Comment: Probably when you pass a size of 0 aswell.

Comment: I see it may return a null or an actual address(based on what comments from other answered mentioned)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. `malloc()` either returns a valid pointer, or it returns NULL. If it returns NULL, your program needs to do something appropriate, like print an error message and exit.

Comment: There are many, many, many systems and implementations. From the link the second answer says: `the very definition of memory exhaustion is malloc not giving you the desired space`. Malloc returns NULL when there is no memory. You can now reason _why_ is there no memory - because it's "super fragmented" or it's too small, or for any other reason (and there are many reasons), but then specify what implementation of malloc and operating system you exactly have in mind. Because right now I think the question is too broad.

Comment: I see, the reason I'm being downvoted is because there are too many reasons to why memory might be insufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When does `malloc()` in C return `NULL`?

`malloc()` returns a *null pointer* when it fails to allocate the needed space.

This can be due to:

1. Out-of-memory in the machine (not enough bytes)
2. Out-of-memory for the process (OS may limit space per process)
3. Out of memory handles (Too many allocations, some allocators has this limit)
4. Too fragmented (Enough memory exist, but allocator can't/does not want to re-organize into a continuous block).
5. All sorts of reasons like your process is [not worthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne%27s_World_(film)#Awards) of more.

`malloc(0)` *may* return a *null pointer*.  C17/18 adds a bit.

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned **to indicate an error**,
>   or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

`malloc(0)` *may* return a *null pointer*. (pre-C17/18)

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned,
>   or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

The **"to indicate an error"** of C17/18 implies to me that a *null pointer* return is an error, perhaps due to one of the above 5 reasons and a non-erroring `malloc(0)` does not return a *null pointer*.

I see this as a trend to have `p = malloc(n); if (p==NULL) error();` to always be true on error even if `n` is 0.  Else one might code as `if (p==NULL && n > 0) error();`

If code wants to tolerate an allocation of zero to return `NULL` as a non-error, better to form a helper function to test for `n == 0` and return `NULL` than call `malloc()`.

---

Conversely a return of non-*null pointer* does not always mean this is enough memory.  See [Why is malloc not “using up” the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359)

Comment: Sorry newbie in C here. What are memory handles and what is meant by point number 2?

Comment: @leon Consider an allocation system that allowed only 1,000,000 allocations (handles) regardless of the sum of their sizes.  Too many small allocations would chew up the handles.  The details of a memory allocator are implementation dependant and another allocator might not have a "handle" limitation at all.

Comment: @Leon An OS may limit each process/program to a max memory usage, say 2 Gbytes, even if there was 64 Gbytes of memory - again an implementation detail.  C does **not** specify details of how an allocator must work.

Comment: Am I then correct to say that 1,000,000 allocations will only be allowed assuming program has yet to exceed the max memory usage of, say 2 GB?

Comment: @Leon, Yes - again an allocater may or may not have a handle limit.  But if it did, the handles could run out before the memory pool is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason, the memory that you ask to malloc can't be allocated or sometimes if you ask for `0` memory, it returns `NULL`.

[Check the documentation](https://devdocs.io/c/memory/malloc)

Comment: `or you ask for 0 memory, it returns null` for 0, it is implementation defined. It may return NULL for 0. It may return a pointer that can later be passed to `free`.

Comment: `malloc(0)` doesn't always return `null`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Either way, the pointer can be passed to `free`, it's just that you can only use the non-`NULL` one.

Comment: Just to be picky, `NULL` is also a pointer that can later be passed to `free`. (`free(NULL)` is defined to do nothing.) It's implementation-defined whether `malloc(0)` returns a null pointer (that can be passed to `free`) or a non-null pointer that can be passed to `free`.

Comment: sorry, added the "sometimes" as reported to the documentation