# With overcommit disabled, when will malloc() return NULL on Linux?

Tags: linux, malloc, out-of-memory

I have a Greenplum database cluster that sometimes failed to execute SQLs because `malloc()` returned `NULL` or `fork()` failed due to insufficient memory (I followed the official guideline to disable `overcommit`). And I am curious the condition of such thing happening. Is this happens when `available` returned by `free` equals 0? Or does it has something to do with `SReclaimable` in `/proc/meminfo`? Will enabling huge page (`sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=3170`) make things different?

**P.S.** I know that `malloc()` returns NULL when system is *"Out-of-Memory"* as already described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850784/8711684, but what I want to know is *the exact condition* that Linux kernel deem the system "Out-of-Memory" so that it will return `NULL` to a `malloc()` call with `overcommit` already disabled.

Any information will be appreciated!

Comment: `malloc()` is not implemented in the kernel, it's a user-mode library. It will fail if it runs out of memory in the heap, or if there's no contiguous block of memory large enough to satisfy the request.

Comment: However, in most cases it will try to increase the size of the heap when this happens. Depending on the implementation, this may call `sbrk()`, and this is where overcommit comes into play. It needs to allocate swap space for it, and you'll get OOM if you run out of swap and overcommit is disabled. Finally, you can get OOM if you use up the entire virtual memory address range of the process, but that's nearly inconceivable on 64-bit systems.